# Viewport width causing background to not show as expected

Tags: css, html, viewport

I am having an issue where the background color is behaving unexpectedly when the viewport is shrunk to a size smaller than that specified for some of my elements. While the scroll bars appear correctly the background is not what I would expect. When the viewport is as large or larger the backgrounds behave as intended. When inspecting the page elements with Firebug it seems that the `body` element is not stretching even though content inside of it is. What's causing the backgrounds to behave this way?

I've provided what I believe to be the pertinent html and CSS, but if I've omitted something please let me know.

**Shrunk Viewport Example**
[image: Broken Example]

**Enlarged Viewport Example**
[image: Working Example]

**CSS**

```
html
{
    background: #A37C45;
}

body
{
    background:
      #55688A url("../images/backgrounds/ns_bg.gif") repeat-x scroll 0 0;
}

#container
{
    width: 100%;
}

#header
{
    width: 730px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#main
{
    width: 730px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#footer
{
    background:
      url("../images/backgrounds/grass.png") repeat-x scroll left top;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 30px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#footercontainer
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #A37C45;
    margin-top: -1px;
}

#footercontent
{
    width: 730px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="header">
      </div>
      <div id="main">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      <div id="footercontainer"> 
        <div id="footercontent">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this behaviour is because your `width: 100%` elements are only taking the viewport width as the amount of background they need to render.

You can fix it by adding a [min-width declaration](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_dim_min-width.asp) to your `body` element's CSS.  Simply set it to the largest nested element's width:

```
body {
    min-width: 730px;
    background: #55688A url("../images/backgrounds/ns_bg.gif") repeat-x scroll 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

min-width is not supported in IE so use the expression

```
body {
    min-width: 730px;
    background: #55688A url("../images/backgrounds/ns_bg.gif") repeat-x scroll 0 0;

    /* IE Version */
    width:expression(document.body.clientWidth < 730 ? "728px" : "auto" );
}
```

Comment: I haven't seen this not work in IE. Are there particular versions I should be aware of?